# What is the big-$\Theta$ bound for this recurrence relation?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

The recurrence in question is the following:

$$
T(n) = 1 \text{ If n = 0}
$$
$$
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(2n/5) + 7n \text{ If n > 0}
$$

What is $T(n)$ in big-$\Theta$ notation?

I couldn't use Master Theorem as it was not in applicable form and I couldn't transform it. I tried to brute-force using substitution but that got too complicated and ultimately failed.

Comment: You can somewhat extend the master theorem by drawing the trees. Or, to use induction to prove that $T(n)\le 70n$

Comment: @JetfiRex Could you elaborate on what you mean by drawing the trees?

Comment: I am not sure whether you are reading the *Introduction of Algorithms* by CLRS, but in chapter 4.2 there is a method called recurrence tree method, with a nice example of $T(n)=T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+O(n)$ in it.

Comment: @JetfiRex I'm not reading that book, but I was planning to soon. Since you say it has this example, I'll definitely be checking it out. Thank you!

Comment: @JetfiRex I read the relevant section from CLRS, but this question is a bit different. $n/3+2n/3=n$ but $n/2+2n/5$ is not equal to $n$. I can see a pattern for the sum at each level (it is $\frac{7n\times9^k}{10^k}$ where $k$ is the level starting from $0$). How can I prove that this pattern does indeed exist?

Comment: ... What I meant is to draw a tree like that and then you derive it yourself... You have drawn that tree and you can derive the sum of each levels like that. Just think of if the pattern goes to infinity, what is the total sum? You don't need to really prove why this pattern indeed exists, you're just going to prove a upper bound by extending the tree to the infinity.

Comment: @JetfiRex I did that and the answer is $\Theta(n)$ (which is also the correct answer).

Comment: So you solved the problem, congratulations! If you need to see why the pattern exists, using induction is a good way to think.

Answer (score 0):

For the recurrence

$$
T(n) = cT\left(\frac na\right)+dT\left(\frac nb\right)+f(n)
$$

considering $n = a^pb^qu$, $\{a,b,p,q,u\}\in \mathbb{N}^+$ with $a,b$ relative primes and $u\not| \{a,b\}$, the maximal paths to extinction are obtained by considering $m=p=q$. In those circumstances, considering null initial conditions for clarity, we have

$$
T\left(a^mb^mu\right)= cT\left(a^{m-1}b^mu\right)+dT\left(a^mb^{m-1}u\right)+f(a^mb^mu)
$$

and after recursion

$$
T\left(a^mb^mu\right)=\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{k=1}^m \left(\begin{array}{c}2m-j-k\\ m-j\end{array}\right)c^{m-j}d^{m-k}f(a^jb^k u)\right)
$$

NOTE

For $c = 1$ and $d = 1$ with $f(n) = 7n$ considering $u = 1$ we have

$$
T\left(a^mb^m\right)=\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{k=1}^m \left(\begin{array}{c}2m-j-k\\ m-j\end{array}\right)7a^{j}b^{k}\right)
$$

or

$$
T\left(a^mb^m\right)=7a^{m}b^{m}\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}2m-j-k\\ m-j\end{array}\right)}{a^{m-j}b^{m-k}}\right)
$$

and for $a=2, b = \frac 52$ we have

$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}2m-j-k\\ m-j\end{array}\right)}{a^{m-j}b^{m-k}}\right)= 10
$$

hence

$$
T(n)=\mathcal{O}(n)
$$